# Did Karl Marx ever say "Life is struggle"?

Tags: quotes

[Ben Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Horowitz), a venture capitalist, has attributed a quote to Karl Marx on several occasions.

- On his [blog in 2012](https://a16z.com/2012/06/15/the-struggle/):

  > Life is struggle.
  >   —Karl Marx
- In a [2013 tweet](https://twitter.com/bhorowitz/status/327198047148847104).
- In his 2014 book, *The Hard Thing About Hard Things*, (p. 274):

  > On my grandfather’s tombstone, you will find his favorite Marx quote: “Life is struggle.”

This last reference is further explained by [David Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Horowitz) (Ben's father), in [*Radical Son*, p. 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=eZt8AKYQAPAC&pg=PA1&dq=%22life+is+struggle%22):

> I had directed the mason to inscribe it with the words "Life Is Struggle," a favorite quote from his mentor, Karl Marx.

However, John Patrick Leary in ["The Poverty of Entrepreneurship: The Silicon Valley Theory of History"](https://thenewinquiry.com/the-poverty-of-entrepreneurship-the-silicon-valley-theory-of-history/), is critical of Horowitz and claims it is a misquote:

> One chapter epigraph, “Life is struggle,” is misattributed to Karl Marx.

I would be curious to know if Karl Marx ever said or wrote this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I have found so far.

- In [*Capital, Volume I*, Chapter 25, Section 5A](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1867-c1/ch25.htm#S5a), there appears the following sentence:

  > human life is but, in nine cases out of ten, a struggle for existence.

  However, Marx is quoting [Gladstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Ewart_Gladstone)!  A footnote says it is from a speech in the House of Commons, 7th April, 1864.  You can find it in [Hansard](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1864/apr/07/the-financial-statement#column_588).  This in turn may have been an allusion to Darwin, who made prominent use of the phrase "struggle for existence" in *On the Origin of Species*, 1859.
- The opening sentence of the first section of the [*Communist Manifesto*](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/ch01.htm#007) (not counting the "specter is haunting Europe" prologue) is:

  > The history of all hitherto existing society is the history of class struggles.

  This is somewhat similar in spirit, but specifically about *class* struggle, which gives it a rather different interpretation.  Also, a footnote by Engels clarifies that "history" here refers only to *written* history.
- In a book entitled *The Technique of the Novel* by  Thomas H. Uzzell, [Chapter 8](https://books.google.com/books?id=JUt9CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT118&ots=xHBrbBNtof&dq=engels%20asked%20what%20is%3F%20marx%20answered%20struggle&pg=PT118#v=onepage&q=engels%20asked%20what%20is?%20marx%20answered%20struggle&f=false) opens with the following passage:

  > Karl Marx's biographer says that one afternoon Marx and his English colleague, Engels, were strolling along a northern France seashore.  After a considerable silence, Engels asked, "What is?"  Marx answered, "Struggle."  Life is struggle.

  Unfortunately, the "biographer" is not identified, and of course [quite a few  biographies of Marx have been written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biographies_of_Karl_Marx).  I searched for "struggle" in each of the biographies whose full texts appear [here](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/bio/index.htm), but didn't find any such conversation reported.